# Trying to plot stock data - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, urllib

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import urllib

import numpy as np


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    str_converter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)

    def bytes_converter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return str_converter(s)

    return bytes_converter  

def graph_data(stock):
    print('Currently pulling:', stock)
    url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv'
    source_code=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
    stock_data= []
    split_source= source_code.split('\n')

    for each_line in split_source:
        split_line=each_line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) == 6:
            if 'values' not in each_line:
                stock_data.append(each_line)

    data, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data,delimiter=',', unpack= True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
    print(date)

stock = input('Stock to plot: ')
graph_data(stock)
```

Here is the error:

```
Stock to plot: tsla
Currently pulling: tsla
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Learn/Mick.py", line 33, in <module>
    graph_data(stock)
  File "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Learn/Mick.py", line 29, in graph_data
    data, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data,delimiter=',', unpack= True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 928, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 928, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A bit of context might be helpful..

Comment: It seems you have partially copied your code from here https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-date-stamps-matplotlib-tutorial/. So, I suspect you might get it working by carefully checking your version against original. However, there is much more simple way to retrieve and draw financial stock data with pandas/matplotlib.

Comment: @tom No, it's still not...

Comment: @tom See the link to the source in my above comment if you're interested

Comment: with the indentation as it is now, this works for me... (and the correction of the typo at the end between `data` and `date`)